# Some properties of Owen's T function

Tags: integration, special-functions, error-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Owen's $T$ function is given by
$$
T(h,a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{a} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{h^2}{2} (1+x^2)}}{1 + x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
There are some properties of the function, which one can find in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function).

one of the interesting properties is as
$$
T(h,a) + T(ha,\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{1}{4}\Bigg(\mathrm{sign}(a) -   \mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{h}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) \ \mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{ha}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) \Bigg)
$$

where the $\mathrm{sign}(a)$ is the [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), and the $\mathrm{erf}$ is the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Now my question is that there is such a similar relation for the following Owen's $T$ functions.
$$
T(h, c \frac{a}{h}+b)+T(a, c \frac{h}{a} + b) = ?
$$

I would highly appreciate it if one could help me find an expression of the above Owen's $T$ functions.

**Edit**

Since this question did not get attention, here I open the first known relation [link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918008812164). Hopefully, this helps

$$
T(h,a) = \frac{\arctan(a)}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(ax) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(h)-\frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
T(ha,\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{a})}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{ha} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(\frac{x}{a}) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(ha)-\frac{1}{4}
$$
therefore
$$
T(h,a)+T(ha,\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{\arctan(a)+\arctan(\frac{1}{a})}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(ax) \mathrm{d}x - \int_0^{ha} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(\frac{x}{a}) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(a)+ \frac{1}{2}\Phi(ha)-\frac{1}{2}
$$
by changing variable, and using integral by part
$$
 \int_0^{ha} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(\frac{x}{a}) \mathrm{d}x \longrightarrow_{x\rightarrow x/a} 
  a \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(ax) \Phi(x) \mathrm{d}x \longrightarrow_{\mbox{int by parts} }
a\Big( \frac{1}{a}  \Phi(ha) \Phi(h) -  \frac{1}{a}  \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(a x) \mathrm{d}x \Big)
$$
thus
$$
T(h,a)+T(ha,\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{\arctan(a)+\arctan(\frac{1}{a})}{2 \pi} -  \Phi(ha) \Phi(h)+ \frac{1}{2}\Phi(a)+ \frac{1}{2}\Phi(ha)-\frac{1}{2}
$$
where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF)
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2} dt = \frac{1}{2} \Big(1 + \mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) \Big)
$$
and
$$
\arctan(a)+\arctan(\frac{1}{a}) =\frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{sign}(a)
$$

**Edit2**

Now for the new expression
$$
T(h, c \frac{a}{h}+b) = \frac{\arctan(c \frac{a}{h}+b)}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi\Big((c \frac{a}{h}+b)x\Big) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(h)-\frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
T(a,c \frac{h}{a} + b) = \frac{\arctan(c \frac{h}{a} + b)}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{a} \Phi^{\prime}(x)  \Phi\Big((c \frac{h}{a}+b)x\Big) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(a)-\frac{1}{4}
$$
thus, finding a relation between these integrations, as it is in the simple one
$$
 \int_0^{a} \Phi^{\prime}(x)  \Phi\Big((c \frac{h}{a}+b)x\Big) \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi\Big((c \frac{a}{h}+b)x\Big) \mathrm{d}x = ?
$$

Comment: How did you get $T(h,a) = \frac{\arctan(a)}{2 \pi} - \int_0^{h} \Phi^{\prime}(x) \Phi(ax) \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(h)-\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire from this https://doi.org/10.1080/03610918008812164, Page 414